# Failed to send email: no recipient

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sendmail

Good day! I need help in debugging this error: "Failed to send email: no recipient". The function sends emails based on the values of a range. Please check the code below.

```
  function sendArticleCountEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Send-Emails"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 5);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {
    var rowData = data[i];

    var subject = 'DepEd Email/Account';
    var FirstName = rowData[0];
    var LastName = rowData[1];
    var GeneratedEmail = rowData[2];
    var Password = rowData[3];
    var emailAddress = rowData[4];

    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: '<h3>' + 'Good day Mr./Mrs./Ms. '+ FirstName + ' ' + LastName +'!</h3>' +
      '<p>Here is your email/account (email and password):</p>' +
      '<p><span style="background-color: #ffff00;"><strong><a name="gEmail">' + GeneratedEmail + '</a></strong></span></p>' +
      '<p><span style="background-color: #ffff00;"><strong><a name="pword">' + Password + '</a></strong></span></p>' +
      '<p>You can now login to <a href="https://mail.google.com">mail.google.com</a> to check your account.</p>' +
      '<p>If you want to change password, login first then follow this <a href="https://myaccount.google.com/intro/signinoptions/password">link</a>.</p>'
    });


  }

  ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 2').getRange(254, 12, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).copyTo(ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 2').getRange(254, 14, sheet.getLastRow(), 1));

}
```

The function runs and sends all emails but then it gives the error. I suspect it loops to an empty row and can't find a recipient but I already have dataRange with sheet.getLastRow().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often there will be a blank row returned at the end from a `Range#getValues()` call. We can add an if statement to skip sending if there is no data in a row:

```
 function sendArticleCountEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Send-Emails"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 5);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {

    var rowData = data[i];

    if(!rowData[4]) continue; //Skip this iternation if no email

    var subject = 'DepEd Email/Account';
    var FirstName = rowData[0];
    var LastName = rowData[1];
    var GeneratedEmail = rowData[2];
    var Password = rowData[3];
    var emailAddress = rowData[4];

    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: '<h3>' + 'Good day Mr./Mrs./Ms. '+ FirstName + ' ' + LastName +'!</h3>' +
      '<p>Here is your email/account (email and password):</p>' +
      '<p><span style="background-color: #ffff00;"><strong><a name="gEmail">' + GeneratedEmail + '</a></strong></span></p>' +
      '<p><span style="background-color: #ffff00;"><strong><a name="pword">' + Password + '</a></strong></span></p>' +
      '<p>You can now login to <a href="https://mail.google.com">mail.google.com</a> to check your account.</p>' +
      '<p>If you want to change password, login first then follow this <a href="https://myaccount.google.com/intro/signinoptions/password">link</a>.</p>'
    });


  }

  ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 2').getRange(254, 12, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).copyTo(ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 2').getRange(254, 14, sheet.getLastRow(), 1));

}
```

**Alternatively**, we can not grab the last row: `var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 5);`